# Format number with no decimal places and no comma in kendo ui in jquery

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do i format value in column of Kendo UI Grid with no decimal and no comma?
I have used below code for remove decimal but now showing coma.

Thanks in advance!

```js
{
    field: "SchCall", 
    title: "Sch Call", 
    hidden: false, 
    width: "15%", 
    format: '{0:n0}'
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Format :"{0:n0}" : If you add "n" mean number format, which add commas and second zero mean 0 decimal.

So, I have used {0:0} for no decimal and no commas.

Reference Link : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting

Comment: I stumbled across this looking for an answer for this question for angular 2+.  For me, on kendo input format was just [format]="0:0".

Comment: @JayCulpepper same here; my paid Telerik support did not know about this either; here is their solution: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7owviu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for React folks, I have struggle a lot with finding a solution in React.

In React, Best possible way to accomplish is to use `NumericTextBoxPropsContext`.

First we need to decide the format and another properties for `NumericTextBox` Component.

```
const NumericTextBoxProps = React.useCallback(
    (numericTextBoxProps) => ({
      ...numericTextBoxProps,
      format: '##'
    }),
    []
  );
  return props;
```

Then we can use this in Kedno Grid or anywhere you have used this Numeric Text Box from Kendo UI in your application.

```
import { NumericTextBoxPropsContext } from '@progress/kendo-react-inputs';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NumericTextBoxPropsContext.Provider value={NumericTextBoxProps}>
        <Grid></Grid>
      </NumericTextBoxPropsContext.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This will help you format Numeric Text Box Filter in the Grid or in general Numeric Text Box  anywhere in the Application based on how we wrap it.